# rsync via ssh from linux to windows sbs 2003 protocol mismatch

Tags: linux, windows-server-2003, ssh, rsync, windows-sbs-2003

I am trying to backup my linux webserver to our local windows sbs 2003 server in the office. I have set up ssh and cwrsync on the windows server and have confirmed that the linux server can reach the windows server via the command:

ssh RemoteUser@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

It asks for a password and connects fine. However when I run this command to start the backup:

*rsync -avz -e ssh home/account/public_html/some/small/directory/ remote_user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/cygdrive/c/backup/destination/directory/*

I get this error after entering the password:

protocol version mismatch -- is your shell clean?

and then it dies.

Has anyone got any ideas?

Thanks

Alex

Comment: Do you have same rsync versions on windows and Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Lots of answers to this question on google, a possible answer is at http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/rsync-e-ssh-error-protocol-incompatibility-345101/ .